# Get records between two dates using Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

In my DB there is a start date and an end date for a certain booking. I want to get the booking records for a certain start date and an end date.
So far I have this in the repo,

`List<Booking> findByPickupTimeAfterAndDropoffTimeBefore(Date startDate, Date endDate);`

and it returns nothing, but there is a record with dates that I'm using in the query in the DB.

**NOTE**: I'm using the java.util.Date here(Ignoring the new LocalDateTime package)

What am I doing wrong here?. Is there any other way I can get the data I'm expecting?

Comment: Hi. You would need to write your own query using the @Query or Criteria that fetches record(s) residing in a specific range.

Comment: What is the DB column type of `pickup_time`?

Comment: @robot Not so. OP's code should work because JPA keywords include `After` and `Before` for date types

Comment: @robot_alien any idea what the query is?
@Query(value = "SELECT vehicle_vehicleID FROM booking BETWEEN pickup_time=?1 AND dropoff_time=?2", nativeQuery = true)
this did not obtain the results for me

Comment: Are your parameter dates the *same* as the dates in the database? If so, your method won't find them because "after" and "before" are false for equal values.

Comment: @Bohemian the dates in the db are datetime im using util.Date on spring boot

Comment: @Bohemian thank you, learnt something new today. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the *same* dates to your JPA method as are in the database, which is **not** expected to return data with those start/end dates, because when the dates are the same, one is not *before* (or *after*) the other.

As per the list of [JPA Keywords documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e1599), `After` and `Before` translate to `where dateCol > parameter` and `where dateCol < parameter`.

Change the method to use `GreaterThanEqual` and `LessThanEqual` keywords:

```
List<Booking> findByPickupTimeGreaterThanEqualAndDropoffTimeLessThanEqual(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

Comment: @PamudithaNavaratne you're welcome. I learned something too! I found the list of keywords supported by JPA, because I needed it to answer this question. Now my JPA Kung Fu is better :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a custom query like this:

```
@Query("select b from Booking b WHERE b.bookingDate BETWEEN b.startDate=?1 AND b.endDate=?2")
List<Booking> findByPickupTimeAfterAndDropoffTimeBefore(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```